# Raspberry Pi VPN Server. Stuck on adding a line to network interfaces file

Tags: vpn

I followed the following tutorial http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing to create a Rpi vpn server. The main difference is the writer here has the eth01 interface set to dhcp and mine is set to static.

There is a part of the tutorial where you add a firewall rule file to /etc/network/interfaces. Since mine is static, it differs from the tutorial. When I try to add "pre-up /etc/firewall-openvpn-rules.sh" to this file, when I reboot my interface is not given an IP address.

I have tried adding it below "iface eth0 inet static" and also after "gateway 192.168.1.254" but either time the Rpi does not get an IP.

You can see the file contents here: http://pastebin.com/9313CDrm.

How do I go about getting this file added and get my Rpi to still receive it's static IP?

Comment: What happens when you execute the firewall script manually? Also run `echo $?` right after the script to check if the script returns 0 — if a `pre-up` script fails, the network interface will not be activated, which might well be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Good question. I am a Linux novice. Let me try and see what happens.

Comment: So I am not sure how to execute it. "sudo firewall-openvpn-rules.sh" ?

Also, here is what is in that file:

`code`
#!/bin/sh 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.100

Comment: Well this might be it..

root@raspberrypi:/etc# ./firewall-openvpn-rules.sh
bash: ./firewall-openvpn-rules.sh: /bin/sh : bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: I used the command "which sh" and it returned back /bin/sh. So I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: That's odd... Run `ls /bin/sh /usr/bin/bash` to see if `/bin/sh` is actually gone. (If it is, you might be in trouble.)

Comment: `ls /bin/sh` just returns "/bin/sh"

Comment: Figured it out. Some random invisible character. I deleted the file and retyped and it worked.